# r filtering for columns with equal values

Tags: r, filter

lets say i have a data set like this

```
`v6 v7   v8  v9
x  123  123  x
x  123  456  x
x  789  789  x
x  123  789  x `
```

how do I filter so that only the rows in which the values for columns 7 and 8 are equal to each other are pulled out, **WHILE STILL** keeping the header for the columns after the filtering? i've tried this code:

`hg19 -> hg19[which(hg19$V7 == hg19$V8),]`

and this code:

```
non_coding= subset(hg19,hg19[8] == hg19[7])
```

where hg19 is the data set. **note**: the real data set has over 99,000 rows and 16 columns

Comment: match with the column names.  `hg19[hg19$v7 == hg19$v8,]`.  You were using `V7` and `V8` instead of `v7` and `v8`. In the second code, it was subsetting the `8th` and `7th` column which doesn't exist in the example (as it was only 4 column dataset.

Comment: i've edited the original post, but the real data set has over 99,000 rows and 16 columns. both of the codes did what I asked, but they didn't keep the column header, which will make the data hard to work with later

Comment: why is your assignment arrow pointing right?

Comment: Also, your example column names have lower case **v**, but the tests are perfomed using upper case **V**. R is case-sensitive.

Comment: What exactly do you mean "while still keeping the header of for the columns after the filtering"? Can you give us the expected result with your example? With the solutions offered so far, it seems like that after filtering v6 and v8 are retained. What do you need?

Answer (score 1):

```
non_coding <- subset(hg19, hg19$v7 == hg19$v8)
```

Answer (score -1):

The code given to you works fine and keeps the original column names.

```
hg19[which(hg19$v7==hg19$v8),]
  v6  v7  v8 v9
1  x 123 123  x
3  x 789 789  x
```